# Deployd + MongoDB not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployd

I have problem with Deployd and MongoDB, I have fully configured deployd and fully functional mongodb, I can run mongod without any problems , mongoDB is in .bashrc file in my path.

The most interesting part is that my deployd used to work just fine, I was creating my first deployd app today, then I went to dentist got back to my home, turned on my PC and it's not working anymore.

When I try to debug dpd I get this message:

```
mongod starting mongod +0ms
mongod error: 1 +6ms
mongod killing mongod +1ms
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the mongod logs?

Comment: How do you check mongod logs?

Comment: Your mongodb logs should be here `/var/log/mongodb` by default. To double check where they are located you can look here `/etc/mongod.conf` the line below this `#where to log` should say something like this `logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#run-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, the problem was that I used wrong installation guide for mongoDB,

I used this guide: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

This installation is pretty small, and it doesn't include things like logs or configuration files for mongodb in /var/ or /etc/ folders.

If you have Linux Ubuntu you should use this guide:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

and everything should be ok.